# Invalidating session in struts based portlet in Jboss portal

Tags: session, jboss, struts, portlet, invalidation

I am working on a Portal web application which was developed with Struts Portlets in JBoss portal. It uses struts-portlet-bridge.

I was trying to add code to invalidate the session before the user is presented the login page, but it is throwing exceptions during `session.invalidate()`. Then I looked at the logout functionality and apparently whoever wrote the code is not executing `session.invalidate()` and I guess for the same reasons I encountered.

Then, I Googled for "Struts Portlet Bridge" and found this link ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19583-01/819-4605/gblnb/index.html) which says:

> If any struts application, deployed as a portlet, is invalidating the session using >session.invalidate(), the session obtained by the struts-portlet bridge becomes the >invalid one. Because of this, the bridge is unable to store rendering related >information. In application server, struts application, deployed as a portlet, must not >use session.invalidate() as the same session is used by struts portlet bridge.

Does anybody have a solution for this? How can I invalidate the session without using `session.invalidate()` in a Struts Action method.

Answer (score 0):

I remember we ran into this issue with JBoss EPP v5.1 we discovered that portlet sessions were not getting invalidated on click of logout and when the user logged back in he could see old data (stored in portlet session during previous login). Also, this issues was fixed with JEPP v5.2 release and we are happily migrated onto it now.